Track NetApp job progress in python library
Im writing a script that at some point deletes a qtree. I want to track the status of this operation (in progress/success or failure in weird cases) inside of my script. The way ive tried to do it is by using the uuid property in the object returned when using the delete() function on a qtree:
    netapp_res = delete_qtree(tst_qtr)
    print(netapp_res.http_response.json()["uuid"])
    del_job_uuid = netapp_res.http_response.json()["uuid"]

    job = Job(uuid=job_id)

    while job.state in ["queued", "running"]:
        print(f"Job {job_id} is {job.state}, waiting...")
        time.sleep(wait_time)
        job.poll()

        # Check final job status
        if job.state == "success":
            print(f"Job {job_id} completed successfully.")
        else:
            print(
                f"Job {job_id} failed with state: {job.state} and error: {job.error}"
                )

but it says that a job with the uuid doesnt exist even though if i got to the ontap web client i do see a job with the uuid and i assumed it had to do with this article:
https://community.netapp.com/t5/ONTAP-Rest-API-Discussions/REST-API-returns-links-to-nonexistent-jobs/td-p/434246
how can i track a specific job then? wehther theres a python wrapper or through paramiko and netapp cli?
note that the json object doesnt provide an 'id' so i dont know what to pass to job watch-progress in netapp cli if i go on that route.
